# Android Gradle compile from mercurial

Tags: android, maven, mercurial, gradle

I want to fetch a project from a mercurial repository in a specific branch with a specific commit id  and use it in my Gradle based project.

same as from maven, for instance like this :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Thanks in advance 
Shimi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a built-in feature for that. You could check out the project using a third-party Gradle SCM plugin, build it using a `GradleBuild` task, and then point to the binary using `compile files("path/to/artifact.aar")`. Or you set up a CI job that builds the project and publishes the binary to a Maven repository, so that you can pull it with the above syntax.

Comment: Thanks, this were the ways i was thinking about going ahead with this, It seems much easier to go with the first solution as i dont need to support a maven repository. Thanks